Networking breaking in a flash drive Ubuntu installation upon connecting to multiple computers
So I have quite an unique issue that I can't seem to find anything on in google.
I'm a new Linux user, two weeks ago I've installed Ubuntu on a flash drive since I needed to take it to my college lab to run it on their pcs on the go. Everything's been working fine on my own computer, I connected it to my home network using ethernet without any issues. Problems started when I took it away, I booted off the ubuntu in my lab computer which also had an ethernet connection, and it was refusing to connect automatically till I entered the IP details manually. After entering the details(like DNS, gateway and etc) it worked fine. Anyway, after bringing it home and running it again on my home computer, I discovered the networking went haywire. It just refuses to connect to my ethernet, the wired options in network settings completely disappeared. I tried an USB adapter, my home wifi shows up there but everytime I try to connect, the WIFI option also disappears but reappears after some seconds, and it keeps repeating. I thought maybe I broke my system, so I went for a fresh reinstallation, and tried taking it away and back again another week. Same thing repeated, the network broke again. Am I doing something wrong here and is there any solution to this? Thanks.
